# Vue - include Vue file into other Vue file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue.

I have created some elements (I'm using Element Components) and the code gets too long.
I would like to know if there is any way to create a several Vue files and include them all to one?
For exmaple, I have Navbar.vue, Header.vue , Footer.vue and Body.vue.

I want to include them all into one file.

Is it possible?

Comment: How about creating an alias file which imports all the vue files you need and exports all of them at once. Then, you only need to import that file for that bundle. Would that solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You import and use them like in my example. Don't forget to register them in the `components` as you can see.

This could be your `app.vue` file

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <the-header />
    <!-- this could be <TheHeader /> depending on your setup -->

    <the-navigation /> 
    <!-- this could be <TheNavigation /> depending on your setup --> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TheHeader from '@/components/the-header.vue'
import TheNavigation from '@/components/the-navigation.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    TheHeader,
    TheNavigation
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

Comment: Whats this code stands for? `export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    TheHeader,
    TheNavigation
  }`

Comment: @E.Bolandian this is what it looks like when you use vues single file components. You can read about them more here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html